# How to update OS X using dmg

Tags: macos

I have multiple Macs and I want to update all those macs using a dmg file. From where I can get the dmg file.
And how to update if the minor version difference is more than one. i.e. from 10.10.1 to 10.10.5?

Comment: The "combo update" disk images on [Apple's download page](https://support.apple.com/downloads/) will take care of updating from any minor version (e.g. 10.10.1, 10.10.2...) to the specified version (e.g. 10.10.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the dmg file from here: https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos

While downloading the dmg please check the system requirement. Because you will need a combo dmg file if you are upgrading from say `10.10.2` to `10.10.5`

On detail page of the dmg there is a `System Requirements` button at the bottom, please check the system requirement from there.

[image]