# Can I update Mac OS 10.11 to 10.11.6 using a dmg of the update?

Tags: macos, software-update, recovery, dmg, bootable-disk

My internet connection is lame  and the last time I tried to update with the download through App store, it downloaded and restarted but said that the `verification of the update package was unsuccessful` . I don't want to do that again .

So, I have manually downloaded the update package (1.55 GB) from [http://supportdownload.apple.com](http://supportdownload.apple.com/download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/Mac_OS_X/downloads/031-63177-20160718-07a49454-4aac-11e6-b616-d6fbcf9f5a9b/osxupdcombo10.11.6.dmg). Now how do I update Mac OS , and also I don't want the verification failed kind of error. I also do know that this happens at some cases when OSx needs to be installed through the recovery section and you sure can fix it changing the systems date, but how do I do it in this case?

Comment: Did you get an actual verification failed error from the link or is this a hypothetical, you wish to avoid an error. What you are trying should work fine so it's unclear if you have a network / disk failure or are just asking if your plan is worth trying.

Comment: To add to what @bmike said, it appears you have already downloaded the proper Combo Update package. You can simply double-click that `dmg` file, which will automatically mount a volume containing the installation package. Open that volume, and launch the installer.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the dmg file from here: `https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos`

While downloading the dmg please check the system requirement. Because you will need a combo dmg file if you are upgrading from say 10.11 to 10.11.6

On detail page of the dmg there is a System Requirements button at the bottom, please check the system requirement from there.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Source: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202377/how-to-update-os-x-using-dmg)

Comment: yeah, but where the heck is the download button? there is a text called download icon inside a box but its just dead

Comment: @Anon click on that button and the download will start automatically.

Comment: @Anon Its not dead. Try again.

Comment: The link is dead when I opened it on OSX 10.6, but worked on macOS 10.13.